# How can I check if NSTextField did change value in C#?

Tags: c#, xamarin, nstextfield

I created a Cocoa application in C# (using Xamarin.Mac) and I want to check if NSTextField did change the value. I couldn't find a lot of tutorials about this in C#, and the methods found for swift or overrides doesn't work for me. I tried this :

```
 public override void ObjectDidEndEditing(NSObject editor)
```

and

```
 public override void DidChangeValue(string forKey)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to check if **NSTextField** did change the value.

- **One** is using `delegate` the same as MacOS native method , however there is a liitle difference with navite code .

As follow :

```
textField.Delegate = new MyNSTextDelegate();
```

Create a class inherite from `NSTextFieldDelegate` :

```
class MyNSTextDelegate : NSTextFieldDelegate 
{
   [Export("controlTextDidChange:")]
   public void Changed(NSNotification notification)
   {
       NSTextField textField = notification.Object as NSTextField;
       Console.WriteLine("Text Changed : " + textField.StringValue);
   }
}
```

- **Another** is using `Event` from C# Method .

As follow:

```
textField.Changed += TextValue_Changed;
```

or

```
textField.Changed += new EventHandler(TextValue_Changed);
```

The implement of `TextValue_Changed` :

```
private void TextValue_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NSNotification notification = sender as NSNotification;
    NSTextField textField = notification.Object as NSTextField;
    Console.WriteLine("Text Changed : " + textField.StringValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In MacOS when using Xamarin, to know when an `NSTextField` has changed you can subscribe to it's `Changed` event.

```
myTextField.Changed += TextField_Changed;
```

And

```
private void TextField_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Here you can access your TextField to get the value.
}
```

Hope this helps.